# Leaflet Map Layout

Tags: leaflet, wms, web-mapping

[image: Layout]

I have been learning how to use [leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) recently and have create a number of maps which have all been full screen maps. I would like to understand how I would place other features on a web page along side a leaflet map?

See the attached image, where:

- Green is the Leaflet js map.
- Red is a heading and some text.
- Blue is an image.

Comment: You should post this on Stackoverflow and you will get an answer within minutes. Just tell them you want to divide your page into three divs. Then you can just add your map/heading & text/image to those divs :-)

Comment: Agree with the other comments re html question, but have a look at some of the Leaflet examples on their pages - some of them have layouts like yours.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a GIS question, but rather a HTML+CSS one. Start by reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning , then do a bit of research on positioning block-level elements relative to the viewport, including how to use the [`vw` and `vh` units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Values_and_units).

Comment: Just to add to this answer... it's helpful to understand that what goes on in leaflet is all happening via javascript inside that div that you set up with the id='map' (your green box). It's just another part of html layout with javascript making the user interaction happen.